# Is it clean code to return in a catch block?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a java servlet which checks for URL parameters (last uri part, wildcard). Given these parameters, I want to respond with a 404 or an actual response. Is it clean code to do a `return;` in the catch block?

```
@WebServlet("/processes/edit/*")
public class ProcessEditServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        ...

        try {
            id = StringManipulation.removeSlashes(request.getPathInfo());
            numid = Integer.parseInt(id);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            response.sendError(404);
            return;
        }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/processEdit.jsp").forward(
            request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some might say "uhh, never do that" - some might say "Yes, cool." - If the `return` at this point is working for you - do it!

Comment: @NathanHughes obviously the auth / validating part is missing. Anyway, I'm forced to use raw JSP, so I figured to use servlets as kind of "controllers" according to the MVC model. Feel free to give me some input how to properly design such applications.

Comment: Don't catch `Exception`! This also captures all _unchecked_ exceptions (ie, `RuntimeException` and derivates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as dognose say, its much about the personal feeling. I would refactor this code as following:

```
@WebServlet("/processes/edit/*")
public class ProcessEditServlet extends HttpServlet {
// you may get a logger over Dependency Injection or joust create one here... 
private final Logger logger;
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...


    if(validateRequest(request,logger){
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/processEdit.jsp").forward(
        request, response);
    }else{
        response.sendError(404);
    }
}

public static boolean validateRequest(Request request,Logger logger){
    try {
        id = StringManipulation.removeSlashes(request.getPathInfo());
        numid = Integer.parseInt(id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(e); // you should at least log the exception
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
}
```

Because, its testabler, and the whole try/catch-block bloat the code and made it less readable - i know peoples encapsulating each try and catch in its own method. However, cleancode means maintainable and readable code - in my opinion its ok when you return in a catch, as long as it makes sense.

Edit1: added logger

Comment: At least log the exception message with the naive `e.printStackTrace();`.

Comment: of course, would be cleaner to log each exception, i'll fix this

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see wrong with the code:

1. No logging to tell later what happened.
2. A generic exception.
3. Where are you returning this to? How about redirect to an error
   page?

But I wouldn't mind the return within the catch block if there is need to do further processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that if you actually catch an exception here, your return statement is going to cause this line of code:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/processEdit.jsp").forward(
        request, response);
```

not to execute.  If you omit the return statement, it will execute even if an exception is caught.

Comment: Which is right, since [`HttpServletResponse#sendError(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError(int)) will write a response. If you do both send the error and forward, you will have another exception.

Comment: Yep!  I was more trying to clarify the implication of using return there and left it up to the OP to decide if that is what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

I think that having a return on the catch can create bugs if after the code evolves catching more exceptions and forgets the return command.

Also looking on a more expressive code, I would say that you want to validate if the request path is numeric or not. So what do you think about this code?

```
@WebServlet("/processes/edit/*")
public class ProcessEditServlet extends HttpServlet {
// you may get a logger over Dependency Injection or joust create one here... 
private final Logger logger;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if(pathIsNotNumeric(request.getPathInfo())) {
        response.sendError(404);
        return;
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/processEdit.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

public boolean pathIsNotNumeric(final String pathInfo){
    boolean isNotNumeric = true;
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(StringManipulation.removeSlashes(pathInfo));
        isNotNumeric = false;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        logger.log(e); // logging the exception
    }
    return isNotNumeric;
}
```